# Cambiar color del borde en Chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

actualmente tengo este código para mostrar un gráfico y quiero cambiar el color del borde. 
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
<canvas id="chart" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ctx = $("#chart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var data = [
            {
                value: 5,
                color: "red",
                highlight: "red",
                label: "text5"
            },
            {
                value: 1,
                color: "blue",
                highlight: "blue",
                label: "ext5t"
            }
        ];
        var chart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que estas usando `chart.js` me tome el tiempo para leer un poco su documentación y ver algunos ejemplos claros. Lo que quieres hacer es agregar un borde a tu figura en este caso de tipo `doughnut`, para poder hacer esto, `chart` nos brinda unas propiedades `DataSet` donde puedes aplicar:
 **backgroundColor**, **borderColor**, **borderWidth**, **hoverBackgroundColor**, **hoverBorderColor**, **hoverBorderWidth**... Teniendo en cuenta esto, es necesario cambiar la estructura como la estas manejando, a continuación encontraras un gran ejemplo.

```js
var ctx = $("#myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [1, 2],
            backgroundColor: [
                'red',
                'blue'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'green',
                "lightgreen"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                'black',
                'black'
            ],
            labels: [
                'text5',
                'ext5t'
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                    var index = tooltipItem.index;
                    return dataset.labels[index] + ': ' + dataset.data[index];
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>
<body>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
       <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como puedes ver en el ejemplo, hay un objeto `datasets` dentro de el `data`, donde especificamos que **[Dataset Properties](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html)** vamos a usar, en este ejemplo puedes encontrar diferentes recursos a usar y que puedes explorar en la documentación oficial **[ChartJs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)**.

Comment: No funciona pero gracias por el aporte ;D

Comment: @PHPLOKKED ok voy a buscar otras solución para ayudarte

Comment: gracias yo también estoy buscando y probando

Comment: @PHPLOKKED como se llama la librería de chart que usas y su versión?

Comment: @PHPLOKKED Aun sigues con el problema?

Comment: Si aún sigo con el problema, usa la ultima version de http://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: @PHPLOKKED ok creo que tengo una solución que te puede servir

Comment: @PHPLOKKED He editado mi respuesta, si crees que fue suficiente para darte una solución puedes marcar como correcta.

Comment: veo lo mismo :/

Comment: @PHPLOKKED Esta bien, lo siento, creo que es todo lo que te puedo ayudar

Comment: No te preocupes, muchas gracias por tu tiempo de verdad, saludos!!

Comment: Hola amigo si me sirvió, lo que pasa esque ayer no se actualizó tu respuesta, muchas gracias de verdad. saludos y gracias por tu tiempo ;)

Comment: @PHPLOKKED Con mucho gusto, recuerda que en la comunidad stackoverflow en español (SOes) estamos para contribuir, recuerda marcar la respuesta como util tambien.

Comment: como puedo marcarla como respuesta útil? el check verde?

Comment: @PHPLOKKED donde la marcaste correcta dale a la flecha de arriba